# Include files in Makefile at the start of a makefile or at the end of the makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to know that if there is a difference when include a `*.mk` at the start of Makefile or include a `*.mk` at the end of the Makefile:

```
include *.mk

all:
     XXXXX

clean:
     XXXXXX

include *.mk
```

Comment: Yes. In general, the order of things in a makefile matters. In particular, rules and variable assignments. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`include` statement does not introduce logic of its own. It is a mere convenience, and equivalent to pasting the included lines into the root **makefile**. So, the order or placement of `include` statements matters as much as the order of lines in the **makefile**.

Comment: Thank you very much